# How do I re-use code from another js file using function in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have 2 different js file: abc.js and func_abc.js

Previously i write all my function in my abc.js and call it from same file. There is no problem this way.

But since it is getting bigger, i am thinking to manage it in separate file as i intended to use it for other file as well.

I am not sure how to call function that i have written in func_abc.js into abc.js

I tried to use export and require but it says Title is not defined.

File func_abc.js:

```
function Title(title) {

    patient.titleselect.click().then(function () {
        element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option',title)).click().then(function () {
                console.log("Successfully select title");

            });
    });
};

function Gender(sex) {
     element(by.cssContainingText('mat-radio-button',sex)).click().then(function () {
     console.log("Successfully select gender");       
    })
};
```

---

File abc.js:

```
it('Create new patient', function(){

    Title("Mr");
    Gender("M");
}
```

Comment: As posted, this has syntax errors.  Please provide a working subset of code that reproduces the issue here.  Also you do not need a trailing semi-colon on a function as you have illustrated in the first code snippet.   What is this "element" function reference there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @yong's answer, it is advisable to use page object pattern for better code maintenance. Instead of exporting the methods directly, Create seperate modules for individual pages in your application and export the class file in the respective spec files. Look at the below example code.

**ProfilePage.js**

```
var profilePage = function() {

   this.Title = function(title) {
     element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option', title)).click().then(function(){
         console.log("Successfully select title");
     });
   }

   function Gender(sex) {
     element(by.cssContainingText('mat-radio-button',sex)).click().then(function () {
        console.log("Successfully select gender");       
     });
   };

}
module.exports = new profilePage();
```

**spec.js**

```
const profilePage = require('./profilePage.js');

it('Create new patient', function(){
   profilePage.Title("Mr");
   profilePage.Gender("M"); 
}
```

Comment: Your way is what i try to achieve.  Thanks. It works perfectly. My code is more organized now :)

Answer (score 3):

1) file: func_abc.js

```
function Title(title) {

    patient.titleselect.click().then(function () {
        element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option',title)).click().then(function () {
                console.log("Successfully select title");

            });
    });
};

function Gender(sex) {
     element(by.cssContainingText('mat-radio-button',sex)).click().then(function () {
     console.log("Successfully select gender");       
    })
};

exports.Title = Title;
exports.Gender = Gender;
```

2) file: abc.js

```
const { Title, Gender } = require('./func_abc.js');

it('Create new patient', function(){

    Title("Mr");
    Gender("M");
}
```

Comment: hafizan, Best practise is using PageObject pattern which is as what @Sudharsan Selvaraj answer did.